# count by several columns in a lapply

Tags: r, string, syntax, count

I'm using a line of code like this:

```
mpg %>% count(~cyl)
```

but now I'm trying to run the counting (and dozens of other lines of code after it) in a `lapply` loop.

What I would like to do is counting the data based on several columns.

i.e.:

```
groupby <- c("cyl", "year", "trans")

lapply(groupby, function(x) { 
mpg %>% count(~x)
})
```

However, I can't get the `mpg %>% count(~x)` to work when x is a string like in the loop.

I tried using as.function() in a few ways, but no success. I'm sure one genius here knows the solution faster than me spending 4 hours on google to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks in advance if you know how to get this working!

p.s. my columns to group by are all factors, 
All other columns are numerical

Comment: mpg in my case is 6 factorial columns, and 90 numerical columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert it to symbol with `sym` from `rlang` and then evaluate with `!!`

```
library(tidyverse)    
map(groupby, ~ 
         mpg %>%
           count(!!rlang::sym(.x)))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#    cyl     n
#  <int> <int>
#1     4    81
#2     5     4
#3     6    79
#4     8    70

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   year     n
#  <int> <int>
#1  1999   117
#2  2008   117

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   trans          n
#   <chr>      <int>
# 1 auto(av)       5
# 2 auto(l3)       2
# 3 auto(l4)      83
# 4 auto(l5)      39
# 5 auto(l6)       6
# 6 auto(s4)       3
# 7 auto(s5)       3
# 8 auto(s6)      16
# 9 manual(m5)    58
#10 manual(m6)    19
```

---

There is also an option to use `group_by_at` with `summarise`

```
map(groupby, ~ mpg %>%
                group_by_at(.x) %>% 
                summarise(n = n()))
```

#### data

```
data(mpg)
```

Comment: a solution that would allow to use count(~x) which understands how to convert the textstring which is x to a column name would be preferable for the rest of my code akrun

Comment: @Mark Sorry, I am not following your request.  Here, the `rlang::sym` is converting the string to symbol so that it can be evaluated

Comment: ah nevermind i failed to understand your answer. It does the same as what I was aiming for: lapply(groupby, function(x){ 
    mpg %>% count(!!rlang::sym(x))
    })

Comment: @Mark I used `map` instead of `lapply` to be aligned with tidyverse.  You can also use `lapply` to give the same output as you stated

Comment: I see. I was originally also looking at an eval(parse(x))) approach or something, but I guess I will add tidyverse to the app's need of packages

Answer (score 1):

Aside from @akrun's more elegant solution you could also do something like this:

```
groupby <- c("cyl", "year", "trans");
library(dplyr);
mpg[groupby] %>% 
    gather(key, value) %>% 
    count(key, value)
## A tibble: 16 x 3
#   key   value          n
#   <chr> <chr>      <int>
# 1 cyl   4             81
# 2 cyl   5              4
# 3 cyl   6             79
# 4 cyl   8             70
# 5 trans auto(av)       5
# 6 trans auto(l3)       2
# 7 trans auto(l4)      83
# 8 trans auto(l5)      39
# 9 trans auto(l6)       6
#10 trans auto(s4)       3
#11 trans auto(s5)       3
#12 trans auto(s6)      16
#13 trans manual(m5)    58
#14 trans manual(m6)    19
#15 year  1999         117
#16 year  2008         117
```

This produces a single `data.frame`/`tibble` which you can process further by e.g. grouping entries by `key`.

---

### Update

The above solution also works on `factor` levels. For example:

```
iris[c("Species")] %>% 
    gather(key, value) %>%
    count(key, value)
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  key     value          n
#  <chr>   <chr>      <int>
#1 Species setosa        50
#2 Species versicolor    50
#3 Species virginica     50
```

Comment: Also a nice approach! One note though, when you run this on a factor column it doesn't work: Error in UseMethod("gather_") : 
  no applicable method for 'gather_' applied to an object of class "factor"
so one would need to change that column to as.character for instance. Akrun's answer works also on factors

Comment: @Mark Thanks & true! Fix by by adding `mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)` to the `magrittr` chain.

Comment: still throws an error; Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. My solution works fine with `factor` columns. It doesn't even need the `mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)` conversion. Can you double-check?

Comment: @Mark I've updated my answer to include an example with a single `factor` column from the `iris` data. No issues here with `factor`s.

Comment: Took me a while to get back to you, but yes, I don't have the bug anymore now. Must have been my R version or session. Have updated to 3.4.4 this week